# how to tweak a style at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a style defined in my `app.xaml` file that applies to all buttons.  By default, all buttons get a DarkGray border.  However, when a certain action on that button occurs, I would like to change the border to Red.

I have done this by creating an entirely new style, defining the `x:key value` for it and then assigning the new style like so:

```
Style style = this.FindResource("RedBorderButtonStyle") as Style;
button.Style = style;
```

However, I have to copy and paste the entire `code` below just to change the border color.  There must be a better way.

Thanks in advance!

```
     <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20px" /> 
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush  Color="{DynamicResource ControlNormalColor}" />
                            </Border.Background>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.9" />
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" To="Pressed" />
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Button has a BorderBrush property, to which you could bind the Border's BorderBrush by a TemplateBinding. Then change BorderBrush when necessary, e.g. in a Style Trigger.

Comment: You don't need to copy the entire style, you can also create a style that is based on another style using the [`Style.BasedOn` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks). This would allow you to "inherit" from your base-style, and only add the setters required for the changed border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining and applying a new `Style`, you could bind the `BorderBrush` property of the `Border` in your `ControlTemplate` to the `BorderBrush` property of the `Button` itself:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20px" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <!-- default BorderBrush:-->
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush  Color="{DynamicResource ControlNormalColor}" />
                    </Border.Background>
                    ...
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

...and simply set the `BorderBrush` property of the `Button`:

```
button.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
```

Comment: I have implemented this solution.  It enables me to change the border brush to red.  The issue I have is that the "DarkGray" value does not appear in the default button.  I can change the color to any color, and it does not show up.  It just gives me the default border color for buttons.  Very odd...

Comment: Did you really add the setter that specifies the default BorderBrush as per my answer? `<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />`

Comment: Something else in my code must be pushing the color off.  This works on normal buttons when I am not manipulating them.  Thank you!!!!!